# How do I add 1 to a value after it's inserted into SQL Server table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Especially for the columns with ID's, I want to add a value of 1 after I inserted a ID into a SQL Server table, so it will be ID +1. Now I can't figure out a way to do this. Does anyone have tips?

Comment: The database does this for you (set the column to identity), don't try to do it yourself.

Comment: *"Especially for the columns with ID's"* don't for ID's. If you want an always ascending value, let SQL Server handle that with an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Yes, It's Better to handle it by Identity, Ex : ```CREATE TABLE City  
(  
  ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar(50)  
) ``` , you can specify ```starting Number``` and ```Increment``` in Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In the table creation script, set that column as identity, so you don't need to mention the column name in the insert script, and the SQL server will automatically fill its value with the maximum value +1.

Here is an example of table creation and how to insert some data into it, and what the result will be.

**Creation**

create table tablename (id int identity,name nvarchar(max))

**Insertion**

Insert Into TableName(name) values('Test1')
Insert Into TableName(name) values('Test2')

**Result**

ID    Name
1     Test1
2     Test2